# Battery drainage during suspend in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, 22.04, battery

I am using Lenovo thinkbook i5 11th gen. My Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version drains battery a lot during suspend mode. It drains hundered percent battery overnight around 6-7 hours.

I am using dual boot with windows and windows sleep does not drain any battery at all.

If i try to hibernate in ubuntu it gets turned off. I am facing lot of issues. Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Some more information is needed here to help you. Can you post exact model of your laptop or include specifications such as if it has a dedicated GPU? That can be of great help to get started with troubleshooting, as often sleep related issues _may_ be caused by f.ex. GPU drivers. You can also do sleep, and shortly after waking up try to run `sudo journalctl -xe` and see if you can see any interesting logs from your sleep session. That info is also super helpful in this situation :) If you can't comment, add your findings to the original post.

Comment: I am using lenovo thinkbook 15 with intel CPU and Iris Xe graphics.